# No match for operator *

Tags: c++

`HugeInt HugeInt:: operator*(int op2)const`
`{`
    `return *this * HugeInt(op2)`;
`}`

The above code is supposed to multiply an object by an int.
Example in the driver it would be: HugeInt n7(5); HugeInt n5; n5 = n7 * 8;
instead of running codes it says that the * does not match. already tried look for other solutions but none will work. The function declaration is under public.

Comment: Please post the exact error you get, not your interpretation of it. That usually makes resolving the problem considerably easier.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error simply because you haven't defined an `operator*(HugeInt)`. You have only defined an overload for the `operator*(int)`.

You'll need to pay attention to your types in C++. If you were to break down your statement, you'd see that the type of `*this` will be a `HugeInt`. Then on the right hand side of your multiplication operation, you have `HugeInt(op2)` which will be a `HugeInt`. The compiler will then try to look up either `operator*(HugeInt, HugeInt)` in the global namespace, or the `operator*(HugeInt)` in your class definition. I would be careful here, because if you correct your multiplication statement to `return *this * op2;`, you'll probably end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: ok thank you it multiplies now.